# copy android room database files from SD card failed

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using this **Java Code** for restoring android room database from SD card and it is works:

```
// Java
public static boolean copyToDirFromMultiFile(File dstDir, boolean 
              createDirsIfNotExist, File... srcFile) throws IOException {
    if (createDirsIfNotExist && !dstDir.exists()) {
        if (!dstDir.mkdirs()) return false;
    }

    for (File src : srcFile) {
        File dstFile = new File(dstDir, src.getName());
        try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(src); OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dstFile)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

And when I tried to implement it with following code of Kotlin

```
// Kotlin
private fun copyToDirFromMultiFile(dstDir: String, originDir: String, fileName: Array<String>) {
    fileName.forEach {
        File(originDir).resolve(it).copyTo(File(dstDir).resolve(it), true)
    }
}
```

Database file has copied but I have to **restart my app**, please tell me something I'm missed, Thank you very much.

Here is document I have found:
[copyTo](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/copy-to.html)

Comment: When is the function called? Maybe the room database is initialized before copying is done?

Comment: Hi @Christopher, call copyToDirFromMultiFile() function when user has pressed restore Button. And room database has been initialized when app start. I don't known why java code works very well but I have to restart app of kotlin code.